# How to Add Image Background on MetroFrameWork C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I use metroframework GUI on Winform. I imported the files correctly. Other controls and properties are fine, but I found a problem, I couldn't change the background of a form to an Image file. I can see a small picture already imported at "Background Image" properties of a form. But the background is still white. Could someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MetroForm I believe only has a Light and Dark Theme (White and Black). This can be changed under "Metro Appearance" > "Theme".

Then you can set a background image under "Metro Appearance" > "BackImage".

To have the image change with the Theme you would set "Metro Appearance" > "ApplyImageInvert" to true.

I don't think there's any option other than the Light or Dark Theme.

Hope this helps

**EDIT:**

To prove that you CAN add an image to the background using MetroFramwork and to negate the downvote.

Here are some screenshots:

Light:
[image]

Dark:
[image]

Settings:
[image]

Comment: Actually, the problem here is that the author hasn't specified which version of MetroFramework he's using. The original version doesn't have those properties, but one of the forks does (the one you're using). I also mistakenly linked to a fork of the [original project](https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui) since I never actually noticed I wasn't using the original one.

Comment: @hankide That makes sense, but still I don't think it calls for a downvote. It is still relevant to what he wants. He just needs to install the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

**In the properties menu set:** 
1. ApplyImageInvert to true 
2. BackImage with your path 
2. BackMaxSize to the size of your background image

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, MetroForm doesn't support a background image. I suppose it's because that doesn't really fit into the *[Microsoft Design Language](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/design)* (Modern, Metro, whatever it officially is called).

The reason you're seeing BackgroundImage in the PropertyGrid, is because MetroForm is based on the Windows Forms Form control that supports background images. If you take a look at the [MetroForm](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework/blob/fb0d0c3cc9b9220bb540102b886c1149fe4877e0/MetroFramework/Forms/MetroForm.cs) and [MetroFormBase](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework/blob/fb0d0c3cc9b9220bb540102b886c1149fe4877e0/MetroFramework/Controls/MetroControlBase.cs) code, you can see that all the painting is overriden and there's not a single place where a background is drawn.

If you really want to have a background in your form, you can fork the project and implement it yourself. It's quite a small addition and shouldn't be much of a trouble.

**Edit**: To be clear, the [original project](https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui), or one of the forks of the project don't have a capability to show background pictures on the form. It however seems that at least [one of the forked projects](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui/blob/master/MetroFramework/Forms/MetroForm.cs) do support Form background images using the `BackImage` property, as mentioned in ryantpayton's answer.